# React: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I've implemented a react context in order to be able to open or close my modals from every part of my app...

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { ModalContextType } from './Types';

const ModalsContext = createContext<ModalContextType>(null);

function ModalsContextProvider({ children }: { children: any }) {
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [Modal, setModal] = useState<React.FC>();

    const handleModal = (Modal2Show: React.FC) => {
        setIsModalOpen((prevIsModalOpen) => !prevIsModalOpen);

        setModal(Modal2Show);
    }

    const contextValue = {
        handleModal
    }

    return (
        <ModalsContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {isModalOpen && Modal}
            {children}
        </ModalsContext.Provider>
    );
}

export const useModalsContext = () => useContext(ModalsContext);

export default ModalsContextProvider;
```

That's my context implementation, then, when I invoke handle modal i pass as argument a component that is the modal that i want to show...
But I'm getting this error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9fGl.png)

I know that I can't conditionally call hooks and I'm not doing that but anyway I'm getting this error...
Thank everybody in advance for the help and I hope that somebody can help me

In my opinion the code is write the right way but obviously it's not.

Comment: What is on line 290?

Comment: The error refers to the bundled file and that is what line 290 is: function ModalsContextProvider(_ref) {
  let {
    children
  } = _ref;
}

Comment: Basically it's the declaration of the children prop that i pass to the context

Comment: Can you remove the `useModalsContext` and useContext directly in the other file?

Comment: I tried but I'm getting exactly the same result

Comment: hmmm... I would look at the rendered JS to see if the transpiler did anything innappropriate. It doesn't happen often, but it does happen. The stack traces are pointing pretty clearly to this component

Comment: I think you're confusing react on what part of the code belongs to which component by passing a function directly as child like that. Maybe simply `{isModalOpen && Modal && <Modal />}` will fix that.

Comment: handleModal(X) is called with X, where X has some hooks in it. Am i correct?

Comment: @TusharShahi you're right I'm passing to handle modal a component that use use state

Comment: I removed the use state and it work properly, obviously as I show That component conditionally even the hooks inside of it is called conditionally...

Comment: However I need to manage the state inside of that component, is there anyway to solve this error keeping the use state?

Comment: Or the only solution is to manage state outside of that component?

Comment: Yes, so that was the hook which was conditionally being called.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible codesandbox? Would make the question better and also would help us in answering.

Comment: Bro you were really usefull but however I decided to keep the logic outside of the modals given that they fundamentally have to return a single value

Comment: I'd like to thank all of the people that spend time to help me...All of you were really helpfull